# two-way binding to select element in Angular 2 does not set selected element on first render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-template

I have the below code I'm using for binding an object[] to a select list in Angular 2.0 (rc 1).
The problem is that the initially when the select list in rendered, it does not pre-select the appropriate value/index.

In the below code example, "ma" is the actual class variable of the component. ma has a SelectedItemType property which is one of the objects from the myItemTypes object array.

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ma.SelectedItemType">
      <option *ngFor='let item of myItemTypes'
                                    [ngValue]='item'>{{item.Label}}
      </option>
  </select>
```

I've tried using the [selected] / [attr.selected] attribute, but it makes not difference. 
Some additional info : 
If instead of the Object, if I bind to the Type property (a string value) using the below code (it works fine):

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ma.SelectedItemType.Type">
          <option *ngFor='let item of myItemTypes'
                                        [value]='item.Type'>{{item.Label}}
          </option>
 </select>
```

But, I would really want to be able to have the Two-way data-binding with the Object. Can you see something I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`ma.selectedItemType` must refer to an item of `myItemType`. It has to point to the same instance, another instance even with the same content won't work.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but I'm not sure as to how do I make it point to the same instance. The problem is that myItemTypes is a separate list of myItemType objects which I'm using to populate the select list. And selectedItemType is coming from another @Input object. They are of the same "type", BUT I'm not really sure as to how should I make them point to the same instance.

Comment: You could look up the instance in `myItemTypes` by comparing the items with the value from your input yourself like `ma.seletectItemType`. `ma.SelecteItemType = myItemTypes.find(val => val.label === myInput.label && val.xxx === val.xxx)`